# Why is it not possible to show that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$ by differentiating the Fourier series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

The Fourier series of $ f (x) = e ^ x $ is given by

$$f(x)= \sinh(1)+2\sinh(1) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+\pi^2n^2}[\cos(n\pi x)-n\pi\sin(n\pi x)]$$

By taking the derivative I get

$$f'(x)=2\sinh(1) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1+\pi^2n^2}[-n\pi\sin(n\pi x)-n^2\pi^2\cos(n\pi x)]$$

But I can't get an argument as to why it can't be shown that the derivative of $e ^ x$ is $e ^ x$ when I derive the expanded Fourier series.

Can you help me with an argument?

Comment: I assume that the sum is over $n$, not $i$.

Comment: @Andrei You're right, I missed it. I already corrected it

Comment: Why are you discussing **divergent** series?

Comment: The series for $f(x)$ itself is convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem on differentiating Fourier series (on $[-1,1]$ in this case) says that we may differentiate term-by-term if the original function is (piecewise continuously) differentiable on $(-1,1)$ *and* continuous at the endpoints $-1$ and $1$. This second hypothesis does not hold for the periodic extension of $e^x$.

Comment: But why is it discontinuous in that interval?

Comment: If you consider the Fourier-Series of $\mathrm e^x$ what you actually do is to consider the Fourier-Series of the $2$-periodic extenstion of $f:(-1,1]\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=\mathrm e^x$. This extension is discontinuous at all odd integers, since e.g.
$$
\lim_{x\searrow 1}f(x) = \frac{1}{\mathrm e}\ne \mathrm e = \lim_{x\nearrow 1}f(x).$$

Comment: frog's point is worth emphasizing: a Fourier series is only sensible for *periodic* functions. If we take a random non-periodic function and take its Fourier series, we're really changing the non-periodic function into a periodic function—and that change can have consequences (to its continuity, in this case). The appropriate tool for non-periodic functions defined on the real line is the Fourier transform.